# Cairo: Why does the Cairo not work in function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

My demo code was like that:

```
   p <- plot(c(1,3,4,5,6,4,3),c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
    myTiff <- function(p){
        tiff("E:/aaa.tiff")
        p
        dev.off()
    }
    myTiff(p)
```

But its does not work(the image was successfull saved, and the size was not 0 mb, but it can`t open), what`s wrong with it?

Comment: What is `Cairo`?

Comment: `p` is `NULL`.  Base graphics doesn't give a useful return value, the functions are called purely for side effects.  Use @MartinGal's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is storing the plot in `p`. Try

```r
p <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,4,5,6,4,3), y=1:7)
myTiff <- function(p){
    tiff("E:/aaa.tiff")
    plot(p)
    dev.off()
}
myTiff(p)
```

instead. In this case your function input are the points to be plottet not the stored plot.

By using `ggplot2` there are other ways since a `ggplot` can be stored:

```r
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,4,5,6,4,3), y=1:7)
p  <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()

myJpeg <- function(p){ 
  ggsave("E:/test.jpg", p) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there no other way? The same custom function can be used through ggsave (p) in ggplot2.p <- plot(...)
myTiff <- function(p){
    ggsave("E:/aaa.jpg",p)
}

Comment: Added an answer for `ggplot2`. If this solves your problem, feel free to accept the answer. :-)